# How to silent an output from Prophet?

Tags: python, output, facebook-prophet

I`m using Prophet (Time series library by Facebook) and it makes a lot of output. Something like this:
[Prophet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wz9rN.png)

I`m already silent some output like this:

```
@contextmanager
def suppress_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
```

But it doesn't silent all types of output, how I can silent all types?

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the Prophet several loggers, which you can silent with:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("prophet").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger("cmdstanpy").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are using an IPython-like environment e.g. Jupyter notebook. Then you can use the `%%capture` [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture) in a cell.

For example,

```py
%%capture
output = do_some_verbose_things(args)
```

By default it also captures the `stderr` which I think the outputs you see are going there.

Comment: Unfortunately, output like: "INFO:fbprophet:Making 4 forecasts with cutoffs between..." (from my screenshot) still visible.

Comment: @josqa Interesting. then please check the functions you are using from that package, they might have some `verbose` or `silent` parameter. You can adjust them e.g. `verbose=0` or `silent=True`. I'm not familiar with that library and you did not share the codes producing so i'm not sure if they have such parameters.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I`m checked this firstly, there is no such parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to completely disable logging for `cmdstanpy`.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("prophet").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger("cmdstanpy").disabled=True
```